# Magento2 Date of Birth not in Checkout when field is required in Address and Name Options

Tags: php, magento, magento2

In Magento 1.9, when you set the Date of Birth Field required in the Customer Address and Name Settings, it is displayed in the checkout form.

In Magento 2.2, unfortunately this is not the case.
Customer Configuration:
[Magento_Customer_Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2wZI.png)
Checkout View: [Magento_Checkout_View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P27Lg.png)

I read about, that the Date of Birth is not in the Address Model, instead it is in the customer Model, and the customer Model is not loaded in checkout, when you are not logged in.

Is there a way, to display the Date of Birth field in Checkout like it would be done over Magento standard? I found a tutorial to add Custom Fields to the Checkout over a Layout Processor (Code is at the end of the post).
 The field is displayed but i have no idea, how to manage the field (names, id, customScope, Datascope, Provider etc.) that it is displayed and handeled, as it would be displayed over Magento standard, so like it did in version 1.9.

The field is needed, to support a feature from a payment module that is used in checkout. The module just checks, if the field exists or not. If it exists it is used and when not, then not. Changes in Payment Module are no option.

Code of the LayoutProcessor Class if this is even a possible way.

```
<?php
namespace XXX\CheckoutAdditionalFields\Model\Plugin\Checkout;

class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
        ) {
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['date-of-birth'] = [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/date',
                    'options' => [],
                    'id' => 'date-of-birth'
                ],
                'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.date-of-birth',
                'label' => 'Birthdate',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'visible' => true,
                'validation' => [],
                'sortOrder' => 250,
                'id' => 'date-of-birth'
            ];

            return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```